# Получить имя пользователя Windows. PHP, JS.

Tags: php, javascript, html

Перечитал интернеты, вроде никак.
Тогда как запустить пакетный файл средствами PHP или JS?
Вообще чем угодно, главное запустить bat с веб страницы?
Ибо echo %username% запросто пишет требуемое.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754437/get-windows-username-of-current-user-using-php - взять имя с помощью php и не парить себе мозг

Comment: echo getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
 global $_ENV; var_dump($_ENV);
 echo getenv("username");

да нифига оно не работает

array(0) { }

Comment: `echo getenv("username");` - все работает.

Comment: echo 'username: --->>> '.getenv("username").' <<<---';
   
выводит: 
username: --->>> <<<---
   
Версии PHP менял от 5.2 до 7.2 Винда 7х64

Comment: пишет логин пользователя на сервере

Comment: Он выведет пользователя, под которым исполняется серверный скрипт. Для получения пользователя ОС для Windows, нужно сделать <?php exec('echo %username%'); ?>
но учитывайте что для выполнения этой команды нужны соответствующие привилегии.